# Bifurcation and ending in an edge image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary, edges

I'm trying to find Ending and Bifurcation points of a binary edge image produced from an ear image.
[image: This is the image that was produced]

I'm writing the code based on the algorithm defined in [this paper] (http://elcvia.cvc.uab.es/article/view/108). I've implemented the part that introduced the formula to find endings and bifurcation. However, I don't get the correct result for different pictures, It's like this formula can't find some of the bifurcations and endings.

this is my code :

```
stats = regionprops(BW4 , 'PixelList');
[numofcomp,x] = size(stats);

BEcell = cell(numofcomp,2);
Ne = zeros(numofcomp,1);
Nb = zeros(numofcomp,1);


for i=1:1:numofcomp

    contour = stats(i).PixelList;

    S = size(contour);
    b=0;
    ee=0;

    for j=1:1:S(1)

          J = contour(j,1);
          I = contour(j,2);

          g1 = BW4(I,J+1) - 1;
          g2 = BW4(I-1,J+1) - 1;
          g3 = BW4(I-1,J) - 1;
          g4 = BW4(I-1,J-1) - 1;
          g5 = BW4(I,J-1) - 1;
          g6 = BW4(I+1,J-1) - 1;
          g7 = BW4(I+1,J) - 1;
          g8 = BW4(I+1,J+1) - 1;


         G1=g1*g2*g3;
         G3=g3*g4*g5;
         G5=g5*g6*g7;
         G7=g7*g8*g1;
          Nc = (g1 -G1) + (g3 -G3) + (g5 -G5) + (g7 -G7 );


          if Nc < -2 
              b=b+1;
              BEcell{i , 1}(j,1) = I;
              BEcell{i , 1}(j,2) = J;
          end

          if Nc == -1 
              ee=ee+1;
              BEcell{i , 2}(j,1) = I;
              BEcell{i , 2}(j,2) = J; 
          end


    end

 Nb(i,1)=b;
 Ne(i,1)=ee;

end
```

I don't know what it's wrong with it ? Have you ever seen this formula before? 
also, I'm not sure about g9 there is no g9 in the matrix which is numbered by paper

EDIT
I used bwmorph :

```
Bifurcation = bwmorph(BW4 , 'branchpoints' ,Inf );
B=0;
for i = 1:1:Size(1)
     for j = 1:1:Size(2)
       if( Bifurcation(i,j)) % 
        B = B+1;
       end
    end
 end
```

%----------------------------- Find End Points ----------------------------

```
 Endpoint = bwmorph(can , 'endpoints' ,Inf );
 E=0;
 for i = 1:1:Size(1)
    for j = 1:1:Size(2)
        if( Endpoint(i,j))
         E = E+1;
        end
 end
 end
```

Comment: Have you looked at `bwmorph` with `'endpoints'` and `'branchpoints'` options?

Comment: Yes, but I want to find the b and e points of every contour (component)  separately ( I wish I could use bwmorph, much easier)

Comment: I don't think you need to need to separately apply for each contour. You just need to use `find(..)` on the output image. Why not give it a  try?

Comment: I just added the code I wrote using bwmorph. I'm going to try    find